# How to stop Firebase event listener in Android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get data from Firebase, when it finishes closed the activity, Firebase still work on listener and I tried to removeEventListener but it didn't work so how can I do it?

```
childEventListener = mOnline.child("Room").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            String val = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);

            opponentPlayers.add(val);
            enterOpponentRoom();

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

and that is how I tried to remove the listener

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {

    Log.d("onStop", "called");


    mOnline.child("Room").removeEventListener(childEventListener);


    super.onStop();


}
```

Comment: How do you know that it doesn't work?  What exactly are you observing?

Comment: Try to unregister listeners onPause() method.

Comment: @Doug Stevenson i had this code in an activity when this activity stop and if some data added to the firebase Database this activity start automatically that means the even is still listener how i can to stop it from listener when the activity stop?

Comment: @patel vatsal how to unregister listeners?

Comment: What do you mean by "this activity start automatically"?  Nothing in the code you're showing starts an activity.

Comment: the activity where i put this code, example this code in activity B when i start that acitivty and close it the event still listener so if i am in the activity A without touch any button the activty B start automatically when a new data add to firebase Database because of childEventListener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a DatabaseReference variable with the final path in the database, mOnline.child("Room") in this case. Then use this reference to add the listener and then remove it. Something happens when you try to remove the listener using the same "child" methos as when you are adding it.

Comment: You don't need to use the exact same reference object for both the add and the remove.  As long as the two references point to the same location, you can add and remove listeners with either one, and the net result is the same.